# How to disable /FORCE option in MSVS linker?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, linker

I have this annoying warning during the linking step of my build process on MSVS:

```
LINK : warning LNK4075: ignoring '/INCREMENTAL' due to '/FORCE' specification
```

I would like to keep the `/INCREMENTAL` option while I don't care about `/FORCE` but it seems like I can't easily disable it. When I go to my project `Properties -> Linker -> General -> Force File Output` there are 3 options all of which are just different flavours of `/FORCE`: `Enabled (/FORCE)`, `Multiply Defined Symbol Only (/FORCE:MULTIPLE)` and `Undefined Symbol Only (/FORCE:UNRESOLVED)`

I don't really want to force generation of an executable when linker fails since exe will not be valid anyways but, on the other hand, incremental builds will be nice to have.

Who knows how to disable `/FORCE` specification?

Comment: Hi ,glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :). In addition, you can give feedback to [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/cpp/report) and  post link here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out while writing the question:

Select any option from the dropdown list and then simply DELETE everything from that line. It should look like this (see the picture attached).

[image]

Comment: In the future you can always refer to options docs to figure out where it is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linker-options?view=msvc-160 also compiler options https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-options-listed-alphabetically?view=msvc-170

Comment: @metablaster, I saw those pages while trying to solve my issue. Both of them don't tell you that you need to leave that line BLANK for the MSVS to treat it as "Disabled"

Comment: That is what linker error tells you, those links tell you where the option is located in VS